# Flex 3: Embedding MovieClip Symbol to Image Control programmatically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, embed, custom-component

I've reviewed all the documentation and Google results surrounding this and I think I have everything setup correctly. My problem is that the symbol is not appearing in my app.  I have a MovieClip symbol that I've embedded to my Flex Component. I need to create a new Image control for each item from my dataProvider and assign this embedded symbol as the Image's source. I thought it was simple but apparently not. Here's a stub of the code:

```
[Embed(source="../assets/assetLib.swf", symbol="StarMC")]

private var StarClass:Class;

protected function rebuildChildren():void {

    iterator.seek( CursorBookmark.FIRST );

    while ( !iterator.afterLast ) {
        child = new Image();
        var asset:MovieClipAsset = new StarClass() as MovieClipAsset;
        (child as Image).source = asset;

    }
}
```

I know the child is being created because I can draw a shape and and that appears. Am I doing something wrong?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply set child.source to StarClass:

```
        child = new Image();
        child.source = StarClass;
```

See the [MovieClipAsset Language Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/MovieClipAsset.html) for more details:

> you rarely need to create MovieClipAsset instances yourself
>   because image-related properties and
>   styles can be set to an
>   image-producing class, and components
>   will create instances as necessary.
>   For example, to set the application
>   background to this animation, you can
>   simply write the following:
>
> ```
>   <mx:Application backgroundImage="{backgroundAnimationClass}"/>
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that but that doesn't work either. I that reference in the MovieClipAsset documentation before. I've seen that when the Image() are is declared in pure AS - and not in an MXML file that this was the correct syntax. I could be wrong but either way its still not working.

Comment: What is in StarMC?  You could add asset.gotoAndStop(1); after instantiating asset in your original code to set the movie clip to the first frame which would then be used as the image source.

Comment: Its an AS3 MovieClip with a frame-by-frame animation. No ActionScript in the symbol. Nothing I'm doing in ActionScript seems to allow this emmbed symbol to appear. I'm using a couple of other symbols from the swf in another component with no problems.